# How to truncate a string in Reactjs and Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';

function SampleArticle({ color, title }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='shadow-md p-4 m-2'>
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: color }} className='h-12 w-20 '>
          <h2 className='text-gray-100 bg-textsecondary text-center justify-center'>
            {title}
          </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SampleArticle;
```

Can someone help with a code to truncate that title to 2 lines
I want the title to cover only one line .The title is in the card

Comment: Did my answer fixed your problem? Please let us now so we can help you out! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a truncate function and use it on title:

```
const truncate = (str, max, len) => {
    return str.length > max ? str.substring(0, len) + "..." : str;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
truncate("My Title", 5, 4)
```

first argument is your string `title`,
second argument is the max length you should check for,
third argument is the length of string you want to show.

And with **Tailwind CSS** you can use:

```
<div class="overflow-hidden truncate w-5">{title}</div>
```

`w-5` is the width.

To use truncate you basically need 4 css properties.

`text-overflow`, `width`, `overflow`, `white-space`

for eg. :

> text-overflow: ellipsis;

> width: 18rem;

> overflow: hidden;

> white-space:nowrap;

Comment: I don't think this answer the question. The key is to use CSS and Tailwind.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the text overflow classes from Tailwind. You have precisely the class `truncate` that includes overflow and also ellipsis for your text.

```html
<h2 className="truncate ...">...</h2>
```

You can read more about it in the [Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-overflow).